# How to redirect to previous page after login in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to redirect to the previous page after login into Laravel 6. I don't know what to change in the `LoginController` class.

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Signin',
            'description' => 'Login',
            'seo_keywords' => 'Signin'

        );

        return view('auth/login', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: why previous page ? not to your next page ?

Comment: Let's say i am on url.com/my-first-blog and on that page user wants to comment on  that page when user click on comment page he/she redirect to login/register page. now after successfully logged in he/she should go back to this url  url.com/my-first-blog to comment on that page after successfully logged

Comment: You can just append query parameter `login?next=/my-first-blog` and take them to `/my-first-blog` after successful login.

Comment: Use the [back()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects) helper?

Comment: @kerbholz how??

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to store the previous URL in a session like this

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
       $data = array(
         'title'=>'Signin',
         'description'=> 'Login',
         'seo_keywords'=> 'Signin'
       );

        if (session('link')) {
            $myPath = session('link');
            $loginPath = url('/login');
            $previous = url()->previous();

            if ($previous = $loginPath) {
                session(['link' => $myPath]);
            } else {
                session(['link' => $previous]);
            }
        } else {
            session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
        }

        return view('auth/login',$data);
    }
```

and then After login redirect to this URL

```
protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if (session('link')) {
            return session('link');
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/dashboard';
    }
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some customization in your login method in LoginController, then you have make some customization in your login controller. see code below

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $data = array(
    'title'=>'Signin',
    'description'=> 'Login',
    'seo_keywords'=> 'Signin'
   );

    session(['previous' => url()->previous()]);
    return view('auth.login');
}


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect(session('previous'));
}
```